# Stubbed specs are taking longer to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, stub

I decided to try using stubs because I've heard that they will make my tests run faster:

They have gone from this:

```
it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
  User.create!(@attr)
end

it "should require a name" do
  no_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => ""))
  no_name_user.should_not be_valid
end

it "should require an email address" do
  no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
  no_email_user.should_not be_valid
end
```

To this:

```
it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
  user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user, @attr)
  user.should be_valid
end

it "should require a name" do
  no_name_user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user, @attr.merge(:name => ""))
  no_name_user.should_not be_valid
end

it "should require an email address" do
  no_email_user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user, @attr.merge(:email => ""))
  no_email_user.should_not be_valid
end
```

But take a good 10 seconds longer to run. My whole suite takes 5 minutes in total. I was expecting a speed boost from doing this.

Comment: `build_stubbed` cannot beat `new`, but it definitely wins over db hits

Comment: Do you have any associations in your model?  See http://blog.spoolz.com/2012/07/09/small-revelation-factorygirl-build_stubbed-associations-and-let/

Comment: Thanks for your collective advice, and the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because I'm including VCR, EmailSpec, DataBaseCleaner and a bunch of other things in spec_helper.rb.

A [tiered spec helper](http://paul.annesley.cc/2012/03/fast-rspec-slash-rails-tiered-spec-helper-dot-rb/) resolves this issue.